# e.preventDefault(); is not working in my modules forms, I tried evertything but can't find solution

Tags: javascript, forms, module, submit, preventdefault

can someone help me?

`preventDefault()` is not working, I tried to addEventListener('click' or 'submit') if I put click required is not working but if I put submit preventDefault is not working i looked everywhere but cand find a similar problem.

```
<div class="modals">
        <div class="pls">
        <h2>Add Book</h2>
        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button id="myBtn">+</button>
        </div>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        
          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <div class="book hidden">
                <form action="#" class="bookTag" method="get">
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" required/>
                    <input type="text" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Author" required/>
                    <input type="number" id="pages" name="pages" placeholder="Pages" required/>
                   <div class="readed">
                        <label for="read">Have you read it?</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="read" id="read" />
                   </div>
                    <button  type="submit" id="add">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
button.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    console.log("heADSFASDGDGDFGADFHDGDAj")
    myLibrary[x] = new book (title.value, author.value, pages.value, read.value);
    addbook(title.value, author.value, pages.value, x, read);
    x = x +1;
    title.value = author.value = pages.value = "";
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.style.display = "none";
})



(I DONT KNOW IF THIS HELPS THIS IS FOR MODULE POP UP)

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it is not working? and which button element you are adding the submit listener on?

Comment: Where is `button` defined? Why would you call a `<form>` element `button`? Or did you assume that a _button_ somehow dispatches a [`submit` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Comment: Here is full code on git hub

https://github.com/Kukii258/Library-.git

Answer (score -1):

Put the e.preventDefault() at the beginning of your eventlistener.

```
    button.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("heADSFASDGDGDFGADFHDGDAj")
    myLibrary[x] = new book (title.value, author.value, pages.value, read.value);
    addbook(title.value, author.value, pages.value, x, read);
    x = x +1;
    title.value = author.value = pages.value = "";
    modal.style.display = "none";
})
```

Comment: This will not make a difference. Events are dispatched synchronously. There is no asynchronous code in the event listener. The [`defaultPrevented`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented) property of the event will be set to `true` when the event listener completes, no matter where you place the `e.preventDefault();` call.